# How to pass multiple models to ActiveSerializer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby-on-rails-4

My Rails controller action looks something as trivial as the following:

```
 def show
    @batter_rankings = DfsHittersBeta.all
    @pitcher_rankings = DfsSpBeta.all
    render :json => ??
 end
```

In this case, both collections above each have their own serializer. I do want to have them as part of one API. So the API will ultimately look like:

`{'pitchers' => [@pitcher_rankings],
  'hitters' => [@hitter_rankings]
}`

I'm not entirely sure how to pass both models to render as json each with their own serializer though and then perhaps a global serializer which allows me to specify how the final output looks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can include both pitchers and hitters in your JSON response like this:

```
render json: {pitchers: @pitcher_rankings, hitters: @hitter_rankings}
```